# Sort information DESC inside joinLeft in order grid magento

Tags: magento

I want to add last comment from 'sales_flat_order_status_history' table.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_status_history',
'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_status_history.parent_id',
array('comment'=> new Zend_Db_Expr(
'(SELECT group_concat( `sales_flat_order_status_history`.comment SEPARATOR ",")
FROM `sales_flat_order_status_history` As `sales_flat_order_status_history`  
WHERE `main_table`.`entity_id` = `sales_flat_order_status_history`.`parent_id` )')));
```

But it's not work. Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

After few days of trying I've found answer:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('
sales_flat_order_status_history', 'main_table.entity_id = 
sales_flat_order_status_history.parent_id',array('
comment'=> new Zend_Db_Expr('(
SELECT `sales_flat_order_status_history`.comment 
FROM `sales_flat_order_status_history` 
As `sales_flat_order_status_history`
WHERE `main_table`.`entity_id` = `sales_flat_order_status_history`.`parent_id`
ORDER BY `sales_flat_order_status_history`.entity_id DESC LIMIT 0,1)')));
```

May be it will be useful for somebody